# Remove arbitrary number of newlines between two tokens with a regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to remove any new lines that occur between two markdown tokens for a header. For example:

```
### This is a long line that
I do not want broken up and I want it
on one line instead. ###
```

The header might be several lines long so it's unknown how many new lines are in the text.

This is what I got so far, but it doesn't strip out all the newlines, obviously:

`s/^(#+\s+[^\n#]+)\n([^#]*#+)*)/$1 $2/g`

See also: https://regex101.com/r/xIHj0r/1

UPDATE: I'm doing this in vim using perl-like regexes using vim's \v tag. So I'm looking for a perl-like solution.

Comment: What regex environment?

Comment: I'm using perlre

Comment: With perl logic available?

Comment: Yeah, it's in vim using the \v option to make them perl-like.

Comment: Stevie, that info should be in the *question* lest you run the risk of getting unsuitable answers.

Comment: Yeah, probably so. I was trying to cast a wide net. I'll add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace matches of the following regular expression with a single space.

```
/(?s)(?:^### |\G(?!(?:(?! ###$).)*^### ))[^\r\n]*(?:(?! ###)[^\r\n])*\K(?<! ###$)\r?\n/
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/izXuMC/4/)<sup>1</sup>

The complexity of the regex stems mainly from the need to avoid removing newlines that are not between header tokens.

Perl's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?s)            : assert single-line mode causing '.' to match
                  line terminators
(?:             : begin non-capture group
  ^###[ ]       : match '### ' at beginning of a line
  |             : or
  \G            : asserts position at the end of the previous match
                  or the start of the string for the first match
  (?!           : begin negative lookahead to assert that '### '
                  at the beginning of a line does not precede
                  ' ###' at the end of a line
    (?:         : begin non-capture group
      (?! ###$) : negative lookahead asserts current match is
                  not followed by ' ###' at the end of a line
      .         : match any character  
    )           : end non-capture group
    *           : execute non-capture group 0+ times
    ^###[ ]     : match '### ' at the beginning of a line
  )             : end negative lookahead
)               : end non-capture group       
[^\r\n]*        : match 0+ chars other than '\r' and '\n'
(?:             : begin non-capture group
  (?! ###)      : negative lookahead asserts current match is
                  not followed by ' ###' at the end of a line 
  [^\r\n]       : match 0+ chars other than '\r' and '\n' 
)               : end non-capture group
*               : execute non-capture group 0+ times
\K              : resets the starting point of the match and
                  discards any characters previously matched
(?<! ###)       : negative lookbehind asserts current match
                  is not preceded by ' ###'
\r?\n           : match '\n' optionally preceded by '\r'
```

This uses the [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) technique, which matches a series of individual characters that do not begin an unwanted string. It is implemented with a non-capture group that is executed a variable number of times, once for each character that is successfully matched. The non-capture group begins with a negative lookahead that asserts that the next character is not the first character of the unwanted string. The first of two uses of this technique here is the following.

```
(?:         : begin non-capture group
  (?! ###$) : negative lookahead asserts current match is
              not followed by ' ###' at the end of a line
  .         : match any character  
)           : end non-capture group
*           : execute non-capture group 0+ times
```

Without the lengthy negative lookahead following `\G` the text

```
Some text
before
### This is a long line that
I do not want broken up and I want it
on one line instead. ###
Some
text after
```

would become

```
Some text before ### This is a long line that I do not want broken up and I want it on one line instead. ###
Some
text after
```

whereas

```
Some text
before
### This is a long line that I do not want broken up and I want it on one line instead. ###
Some
text after
```

is wanted.

<sup>1 Note that the "SUBSTITUTION" box at the link contains a single space.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I spent some time and tinkered with this and in Perl I can do: `s/(^(#+)\s.*?\g2)/$1 =~ s|\n||rg/gmse;`. Now the question is whether this can be done in vim.

Answer (score 0):

import re

string = 'I do not want broken up and I want it\non one line instead.'

new_string = re.sub('\n', ' ',string)

print(new_string)

Comment: I suppose that's one way to do it. But there may be several of these strings in a file. It would be better to do a regex on them all rather than do a search and replace on each substring.

Comment: this method will substitute all occurrences of \n with space.